# Merging issue on R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge a 100-column dataset with roughly 5k rows (df1) with a single column of another dataset (df2$X), based on the ID column.

E.g.

```
df1:

Id    Price   Animals 
2     1       Dog
3     1       Cat
4     3       Dog
5     4       Cat
6     5       Mouse
10    9       Cat
16    0       Cat
14    4       Cat

df2: 
Id    X   
2     Kiwi      
5     Banana    
6     Apple      
7     Berries      
8     Mango      
10    Melon
```

The resulting dataset should be:

```
Id    Price   Animals  X
2     1       Dog      Kiwi
3     1       Cat      NA
4     3       Dog      NA
5     4       Cat      Banana
6     5       Mouse    Apple
10    9       Cat      Melon
16    0       Cat      NA
14    4       Cat      NA
```

I tried doing:

```
merge(df1, df2, by="Id")
```

but this seems not to be working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have duplicate columns in both the dataframe you can select only the columns that you need before `merge`.

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2[c('Id', 'X')], by= "Id", all.x= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2)
Joining, by = "Id"
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     Id Price Animals X     
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr> 
1     2     1 Dog     Kiwi  
2     3     1 Cat     NA    
3     4     3 Dog     NA    
4     5     4 Cat     Banana
5     6     5 Mouse   Apple 
6    10     9 Cat     Melon 
7    16     0 Cat     NA    
8    14     4 Cat     NA    
>
```

Comment: Thanks! but it is not working for me?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: It simply does not show the additional column in the df1.

Comment: Not sure how that's possible, are you selecting an particular columns before joining?

Comment: df1$X <- left_join(df1, df2, by="ID")
Like this, it works but weirdly the columns are copied twice (so I have Id.X, Animal.X etc.)

Comment: Just `df1 <- left_join(etc)`, no `$X`!